# Can Find My iPhone password be different than my Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, find-my-iphone

Can my Find My iPhone password be different than my Apple ID password? I would like it to be different so my girlfriend can see where I am but not be able to access my entire phone.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

Your alternative would be to use the [Find My Friends](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/find-my-friends/id466122094?mt=8) app, which should be already installed in anything since iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve removed **Find My Friends** or would rather not use it, an alternative is to share your location via the **Messages** app. Since you and your girlfriend probably text each other, this is a very convenient option, especially if you’re not going to share your location with anyone else.

Open her conversation thread, then tap the ⓘ in the upper-right corner.

[image]

On the next screen, tap *Share My Location*. You can choose from several options, including *Indefinitely*.

[image]

Now if she opens her conversation thread with you, she will see your location by tapping that same ⓘ

Note that **Messages** and **Find My Friends** share this information, so she would also be able to see your location in **Find My Friends** (including in the **Today View** widget).